# Prove the cube root of $36$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Prove the cube root of $36$ is an irrational number.

Proof by contradiction: let it equal $\frac{a}{b}$, where $\frac{a}{b}$ is in its simplest form and
$b$ does not equal $0$.

$36 = \frac{a^3}{b^3}$

Therefore, $36$ is a factor of a cubed. Since $36 = 2 \times2 \times 3 \times 3$  then by prime factorization, we can deduce that using Euclid’s Lemma if $gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $a | bc$ then $a | c$, such that $2| a$ and $3| a$.

Ok, I understand all of this. Now, what is next?
Do I say then let $a= 2c$? I tried that and couldn't prove it.
The same happens if I, say, let $a= 3c$.
Can I just multiply $2$ by $3$ and state that $6| a$? If I use $a = 6c$, then I know how to finish this problem. I don't want the solution. I just need to know the reasoning behind using $a= 6c$.

Comment: Your assumption is 2|a and 3|a and you want to get to a contradiction. So you can use everything you can directly get out of these two assumptions. One is directly 6|a, and then you said you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Since $36b^3=a^3$, you see that $2\mid a$, so $a=2x$. After simplifying,
$$
9b^3=2x^3
$$
which implies that $2\mid b$. Contradiction, because by assumption $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$36 = \frac{a^3}{b^3}$$
$$6^2b^3 = a^3$$
$$2^23^2b^3 = a^3$$
This implies that a is even, or
Let a = 2c
$$ 2^2 3^2 b^3 = 8c^3$$
$$3^2b^3 = 2c^3$$
b is also also even which means gcd (a,b) is not 1 which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\sqrt[3]{36}=\frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{6}}=\frac ab \iff \sqrt[3]{6}=\frac{6b}{a}.$$
Cube root of $6$ is irrational (see [here](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/real-numbers/real-numbers.faq.question.243988.html)), so is the cube root of $36$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I figured out what to do.This was more a clarity issue in explanation. No need to comment anymore. I've used the method I mentioned above and have worked out how to explain it concisely.